# Locking down Amazon RDS table data

Tags: encryption, access-control, amazon, content-security-policy

We are using MySQL Amazon RDS. The instance is encrypted, and also only available via SSH from the production server EC2 instance.

One of the things we are trying to do is give access to some critical data that that we collect and store in this database to ABSOLUTELY NO ONE, NOT EVEN our employees for support. Given this might mean that we cannot have technical support. Some of the data in some tables is OK to be viewed and accessed by our internal employees for emailing, marketing etc., So questions

1. How does the industry handle such a user scenario, where some of the
   data in some of the tables, some of the tables themselves need to be locked down, and only available to the end users via secure API's
2. Is there a way to completely lock down the data of the users that no
   one can see them even with regular sql code?
3. Is it possible to lock particular rows in the table also based on
       some parameter?

Answer (score -1):

I don't even play a DBA on TV, but I used different (google) bigtables with different access permissions, joined when accessed by the privileged users, via either the GUI or the sorta-nosql language.

For the others, you might need a system with Mandatory Access Control and a DBMS that understands them.  Existed once, but not a business success, so I somewhat doubt they're easily available (:-))